# How to position absolute div relative to other div

Tags: html, css

I have two div's.

For first div I have `position:absolute` and for second div I just have `margin-top:50px.`

Assuming the first div (which one have position absolute) has some data from backend

No matter how my text is long, how can I always have 50px gap from first div to second

[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-wind-yq45r)

```css
.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}

.box2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply
</div>
<div class="box2">box 2</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code required to reproduce your problem, needs to be contained directly inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: I there a reason that the first div is absolute? It sounds like it ought not to be if you want the second div to follow on from the bottom of it.

Comment: _“how can I always have 50px gap from first div to second”_ - you can’t. Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal layout flow, so that it does not influence the position of any following elements any more.

Comment: I made you the snippet using the `[<>]` snippet editor and cut down on the waffle

Comment: If you remove the position:absolute, your problem is solved. Is there any reason you are using absolute position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```css
   
   .wrap{
     position: absolute;
        top: 0;
   }
   .box1 {
        
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 100px;
      word-break: break-all;

    }
    .box2 {
      position:absolute;
      margin-top: 50px;
      border: 1px solid green;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="box1">
          Lorem Ipsum is
        </div>
        <div class="box2">box 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution don't fix your first div with `position: absolute;`
I propose you this solution

```css
.main {
  display: block;
}
.box1 {
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}
.box2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box1">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply
         Lorem Ipsum is simply
          Lorem Ipsum is simply
           Lorem Ipsum is simply
  </div>
  <div class="box2">box 2</div>
</div>
```